# Really Distorted Stereo Calibration Images OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

What I want to do is overlay stereo images together. 
Given a sample set of stereo images I was able to display rectified images of them.
However, given a set of stereo images taken for the Microsoft Kinect, RGB and Infrared, I get really distorted images.

The original and rectified images can be found in the link:
http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/8021/calibration.png

I used the same code for the same set of images. I have tried multiple sets of Kinect "stereo" images and they all came out very distorted.

I am wondering what could be wrong?

The way I am displaying the images is:

I use cvStereoCalibrate() with these two as the last parameters: ...cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5), CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO }

I then use cvStereoRectify and get mapx and mapy of the RGB camera using cvInitUndistortRectifyMap() then cvRemap and display the images.

I was wondering if the parameters of cvStereoCalibrate greatly affect the Kinect "stereo" images?

Thanks,
Tyro

Answer (score 0):

I notice that one of the images has much less brightness and contrast in your samples.  While it does find the corners, less brightness and contrast will result in a lot of error in the subpixel accuracy.  I struggle a lot with rectification too and find that setting everything up perfectly (to the point of needing less rectification) is the only way to get really good results.

Answer (score 0):

You use too small pattern for calibration.